# Turbogears2 and py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, turbogears, pytest

I'm switching our testing environment from Nose to py.test for testing a Turbogears2 web application.

Currently, when Nose runs it gathers information from a testing configuration file (test.ini) that holds all the testing variables the application needs. And it seems to do so in an automatic way (I'm simply running `nosetests` and everything gets loaded)

The problem relies in the inability for py.test to be pointed at the right INI configuration file so that I can get the app loaded with the variables I need.

Currently, the failing point is pylons.app_globals which is simply non-existent when running py.test (hence everything fails).

I have been through the Turbogears documentation but they only mention Nose/nosetests and nothing else.

Is there a way to be able to lead the application with the testing variables I rely upon with py.test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as py.test's part is concerned, you can implement something like this:

```
# content of conftest.py
def pytest_sessionstart():
    # setup resources before any test is executed

def pytest_sessionfinish():
    # teardown resources after the last test has executed
```

Such a conftest.py file should currently best live at your checkout root directory as py-1.3.4 will only run this hook if it sees it early enough.

I also looked a bit around TurboGears but didn't erasily found the mechanism how/which test.ini is actually loaded. I can update the answer if somebody can provide this information.

HTH. Holger

Comment: wow, thanks Holger! it is really humbling to get an answer from you! you rock! As to the problem itself, the way nose was gathering app values via setUp method.

Comment: your welcome, alfredo.  do you have a URL pointing to the code which implements this setUp functionality and maybe contains some example tests?

Comment: unfortunately no, it is not an OSS project. However, I have a better insight as to what has been going on. Basically we were implementing a TestSetupCommand class that would bring everything up to speed, so I'm porting that to match py.test requirements.